# How to remove the last comma in javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

```
let str = "Testing, how to, remove, comma"
```

How can I remove that last comma (,) between "remove" and "comma" using JavaScript? Preference using replace with regex

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably better ways than using regular expressions, but you can do this:

str.replace(/,([^,]+$)/, "$1")

```js
const str = "Testing, how to, remove, comma"

console.log(str.replace(/,([^,]+$)/, "$1"));
```

The regular expression matches a comma, then in a group it matches everything that is not a comma until the end of the string. The replacement is "$1", which is the first capturing group, meaning everything after the last comma.